# Dart A value of type 'num' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'

Tags: dart

I have a list of integers and strings, and I tried to add up all the integers in the list together, but it gives me an error saying that the variable type is a 'num', and can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'

```
void main() {
  List test = [
    [1, 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    [2, '1', '2', '3'],
    [3, 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
  ];
  int total = 0;
  test.forEach((item) => total += item[0]);
}

A value of type 'num' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'int'.
```

I've tried int.parse, .toInt(), didn't help. How do I convert that num to int?

Comment: You would need to cast from `dynamic` to `int`: `item[0] as int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void main() {
 List test = [
   [1, 'A', 'B', 'C'],
   [2, '1', '2', '3'],
   [3, 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
];
//initailize total as num instead of int;
num total = 0;
test.forEach((item) => total += item[0]);
```

}

Comment: That's hiding the problem rather than solving it. I'd use `(item[0] as int)` to tell the compiler that the `dynamic`-typed value is actually an integer.

The problems comes from `int.+` being defined as taking a `num` and returning a `num`, with a special case when it can statically see that the second operand is an `int`. When the second operand has type `dynamic`, that's not the case, and with the Dart Null Safety release, you no longer get implicit downcasts from `num` to `int`.